# Knockout return observable array from json

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this view model that is getting data from entity famework. i am able to convert it successfully from JSON to an array but it's not observable.  I have tried creating a model that has observable properties and then populating with a for each but that didn't seem to work . I also tried using ko.mapping.fromJSON that seemed to work ok on the service side but its always empty on the view.

```
function(logger, system, router, employeeService) {
var EmployeeDetails = ko.observableArray([]);


Activate Function -
    var activate = function () {
    return  GetEmployeeDetails(),GetTermList();
    };

 var vm = {
       activate: activate,
        FindID: ko.observable(),
        EmployeeDetails:  EmployeeDetails
     }


};


function GetEmployeeDetails() {
      return employeeService.getemployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails);

    }
```

//This is the function in my employeeService class

```
 var getEmployeedetails = function(employeeDetailsOb) {
        var jsonfromServer;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/api/employee/getAllDetails/",
            data: '{}',
             success: function(data) {
                jsonfromServer = $.parseJSON(data);

      },
 error:
{ //error stuff})

Return employeeDetailsOb(jsonFromServer);
}
```

Comment: Please clean up the code formatting.  It looks like your returning your employeeDetailsOb(jsonFromServer) outside of your success handling... which usually executes after your return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to return EmployeeDetails() object from getEmployeeDetails(...) before you actually successfully return from that call, try putting your vm.EmployeeDetails initialization inside your sucess handler:

```
success: function(data) {
    jsonfromServer = $.parseJSON(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < jsonFromServer.list.length; ++i)
    {
        vm.EmployeeDetails.push(jsonFromServer.list[i]);
    }
},
```

Comment: It currently returns data in this way but I need the individual propeerties to be observable

Comment: In that case, construct new employeeDetails instances inline and add them to the observable array.  When you make your ed view models, make sure to assign each property as ed.prop1 = ko.observable(jsonFromServer.list[i].prop1);

Answer (score 0):

I think once EmployeeDetails has been set as an observable array you can just set your observable array data like this:

```
vm.EmployeeDetails(jsonfromServer.list);
```

Comment: To make each result observable instead, do a loop over the jsonFromServer and do vm.EmployeeDetails.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonFromServer.list[i]));

Comment: You'll need the mapping plugin for this, though.